# How to find employers that use a certain technology

Tags: job-search, employer, location

I do a lot of math and science research, and I code exclusively in Matlab, at a research university.

I recently started looking around for an industry job but found that nearly all employers ask for coding backgrounds in C++, Java, or Python.  The only employer that favors Matlab is MathWorks, the maker of Matlab.

How and where could I search a little deeper to find some employers that use Matlab?

As for location, I'm interested in working in California, Boston, and New York City.

Comment: Are you desperate to stay writing MATLAB or would you consider learning another language if an employer was prepared to invest in that? As you're discovering, MATLAB shaped holes are pretty rare.

Comment: @PhilipKendall good question; I'd certainly consider learning another language, if the job offer were decent, overall, although I really enjoy modeling and simulations, and all the great tools from the Matlab File Exchange community, and I'd like to maximize my time doing modeling work, and minimal time coding.  What would you suggest?  Should I leave some note on my resume that says something to the effect of, "willing to learn a new programming language"?  Thanks

Comment: If you want to do modelling and simulations then Python would be a great language to learn. It's replacing MATLAB in many domains. Check out what people are doing with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many employers hire people with MATLAB skills in industries as diverse as financial technology, marine engineering, and image analysis in neuroscience and astronomy.

**Frequent MATLAB-related locations** online and in real-life. Examples include online forums where people discuss using MATLAB in specific problem domains. Also, local meet-ups related to MATLAB or uses of MATLAB.

**Search job forums** for MATLAB and see who is hiring.

**Contact recruiters** in cities you want to work and judge how eager they are to talk to you.

**Check out the MathWorks website** where they have stories about companies and institutions using MATLAB.

**Talk to your university professors**, especially adjunct professors about companies they may have partnered with who use MATLAB.

Comment: You can also look for employees using MATLAB on e.g. LinkedIn. Although that's probably one of the less-good suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I've tried a bit of all your suggestions except for the last: asking my university professors.  I almost feel at risk of being judged by them negatively, since my research is currently in a pretty serious phase (e.g. midway between start of an idea and a paper submission).  I guess as more time passes, I might feel more comfortable having these discussions with them.

Comment: Mathworks has done a good job developing an "ecosystem" around their core products. There are many companies selling addons. Look here. https://www.mathworks.com/products/connections/search-services.html?q=&page=1 .  Find out if some of them are hiring. They run trade shows all over the world. http://www.matlabexpo.com/ Go to one.

Answer (score 3):

Who's hiring in your field?

Mathworks themselves. They're a big sponsor of public radio in my area, announcing plenty of job openings.

They have done a good job developing an "ecosystem" around their core products. There are many companies selling addons. Look here. https://www.mathworks.com/products/connections/search-services.html?q=&page=1 .

Maybe you work with one or more of these addon products. At any rate you can use this list of addon providers as prospective employers.

Mathworks runs trade shows all over the world. http://www.matlabexpo.com/  Print up a bunch of business cards saying you're looking for work and giving your contact information, and print up some resumes / CVs. Go to one of the trade shows and talk to everybody. Ask people, "What do you do?" and "Do you know anybody who's hiring?"

Believe me, these questions aren't rude or a sign of weakness. Not at all. People want to make connections and help other people get started in a specialized field.

You're looking for work at a good time. Many employers have openings.

And: diversify your skills as you are able.  (I started out as a chemistry grad student, programming image stuff in FORTRAN. I now use Javascript and other languages. Long careers aren't tied to particular technology stacks.)